# jquery to dynamically add table row with value upon entering text input using enter key more than two column

Tags: php, jquery

1.html

```
<table  id="cstbl" border="1">
    <tr  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
    <td>no</td>
    <td>item no</td>
    <td>descr</td>
    <td>uom</td>
    <td>qty</td>
    <td>upr</td>
    <td>disc</td>
    <td>sub</td>
    <td>x</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
Enter barcode: 
<input type="text" name="barcode" id="barcode" />​
```

2.javascript

```
var index = 1;
$('input[name=barcode]').on('keyup',function(e){
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    $('table').append('<tr><td></td><td></td> <td></td><td></td><td></td> <td></td> <td></td><td></td><td></td> </tr>');    
    $('table tr:last td:first').html(index);
    $('table tr:last td:last').html($(this).val());
    $(this).focus().select();
    index++;
  }
});​
```

If I want to display the value of `barcode` in `table cstbl` in second column which is item no column, what are the script for replace the `td:last` in the javascript?

I just know only have `:first` and `:last` selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/3a98C/)**

```
var index = 1;
$('input[name=barcode]').on('keyup',function(e){
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    $('table').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td> </td><td></td><td></td> </tr>');    
    $('tr:last td:eq(0)').html(index);
    $('tr:last td:eq(1)').html($(this).val());
    $(this).focus().select();
    index++;
  }
});​
```

Comment: is it possible to submit the data in table cstbl in database?

Comment: how can i use the input type in each cell every row? can i use <td><input type='text' id='itemno0' name='itemno0' size='30' /></td> in append() function?

Comment: example,                                                 $('table').append('<tr><td><input type='text' id='itemno' /></td><td><input type='text' id='descr' /></td><td><input type='text' id='uom' /></td><td><input type='text' id='qty' /></td><td><input type='text' id='upr' /></td><td><input type='text' id='disc' /></td><td> </td><td><input type='text' id='sub' /></td><td><input type='button' id='x' /></td> </tr>');                               if i write like this,it can work or not?

Comment: in this part,$('tr:last td:eq(1)').html($(this).val());, how can i pass the value in barcode to textfiled itemno?

Comment: try this `$('tr:last td:eq(1) input:text').val($(this).val());`

Comment: it works...can i know whether id or name of input text is same every time it append the row?if it same,how can i change the name of textfield because i want to submit the value of each row to database.. ..

Comment: like item no `name='itemno_"+index+"' name='descr_"+index+"'` 
fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/3a98C/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yo can add these values directly while building new row:

```
$('#cstbl').append(
'<tr>' +
    '<td>' + index + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
'</tr>');
```

Or filter all td's to match only second one (in 0-indexed array, that's why 1):

```
$('table tr:last td').eq(1).html($(this).val());
```